# curve25519 by openSSL

Tags: elliptic-curves, openssl, key-generation, elliptic-curve-generation

How can i generate ec curve25519 keys using openSSL?
When I run

```
openssl ecparam -name curve25519 -genkey -noout -out private.ec.key
```

I have this message

```
unknown curve name (curve25519)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the `genpkey` command:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm x25519
```

or, for edwards25519:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519
```

This requires a recent OpenSSL version.

Comment: openssl say: `Algorithm x25519 not found`

Comment: Your OpenSSL version is too old.

Comment: when i run `openssl version` it answer with `LibreSSL 2.6.5`

Comment: You need to update your openssl version to 1.1.1 minimum

Comment: @camp0+ 1.1.0 has x25519; 1.1.1 adds ed25519 x448 ed448 . Libre, although it started as a fork, is now separate and I don't know its status/history.